# Making all possible 6 digit combinations of digits and alphabets

Tags: python, hash, sha1, python-itertools, brute-force

I am trying to do a brute force on one hash key i have , key is 28 bit and i have to find password which is 6 digit and includes 0-9 and a-z like 36 total possibilities for each place.

I am using macbook with 16gb of ram but when i run following code it takes forever and eventually kills the process for using too much memory what i want to know is how to overcome it and secondly is it possible that instead of waiting for this whole loop to finish and then iterative abc to get all combinations and then passing them to SHA1 hash function i can pass combinations to hash function as they are being generated

```
abc = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",repeat=6)]
```

Comment: Simply loop over the result of `itertools.product` and do whatever calculations you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create the list just iterate over the `itertools.product object`  getting one value at a time to avoid storing all in memory at once:

```
for ele in  itertools.product("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",repeat=6):
    print("".join(ele))

000000
000001
000002
000003
000004
000005
000006
000007
000008
000009
00000a
00000b
00000c
00000d
00000e
00000f
00000g
00000h
00000i
00000j
00000k
00000l
00000m
00000n
00000o
00000p
00000q
00000r
00000s
00000t
00000u
00000v
00000w
00000x
00000y
...............
```

Comment: Do i just pass each value one by one to hash function and see if i get a match or is there a faster alternative as well like maybe threading or something to find the match quickly or something else i don't think threading will be of any use here

btw thanks your answer does solve my query :)

Comment: No worries, yes just pass each value. You could use multiprocessing sharing the iterator.

Comment: Can you give me a head start on where do i look in order to do multiprocessing ?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the object that `itertools.product()` returns, like you're actually already doing with the list comprehension, like this:

```
import itertools, string
for i in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits,repeat=6):
    if check_hash("".join(i)):
        print i
        break
```

This will only store the current one in memory.

There are (26+10)^6 = 2176782336 possibilities, so it will still probably take a while. With each one taking up 6 bytes, your original solution used 13060694016 bytes, or a little more than 12 GB.

I'm also using Python 2's [string constants](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-constants) instead of typing out the letters and numbers.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I did. To answer your original question, I tried to explain my answer more thoroughly.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, of course it doesn't provide a different solution. That doesn't mean more explanation is bad.